# Examples of elements of $C(Y)$ for closed set $Y$ in compact $X$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact set and $Y$ be closed subset of $X$. Consider two examples below

1. $X = [0, 1]$, $Y=\left\{\frac {1}{2^k} : k\in \mathbb N\right \} \cup \{ 0\}$ or take $Y$ to be finite number of points.
2. $X = [0, 1]$, $Y=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{B}\left(\frac 1 {2^n}; \frac 1 {4^{n+1}}\right )$ or take $Y$ to be finite number of closed intervals.

If $f\in C(Y)$ and $f$ has an extension in $g\in C(X)$ s.t. $g\mid_Y=f$. In case 1, is $f$ a constant sequence or can it assume any value? In case 2, if $Y = \dots,a] \cup [b, \dots$ then should $f(a) = f(b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, the identity function $f(x)=x$ works, so $f$ need not be constant. Also $f$ can assume any values as long as the sequential criterion for continuity hold at each point. Like in the 2nd case you can take $f(x)=1$ in one closed interval and $f(x)=2$ in the next closed interval.

Comment: I thought about it and I found out that I was "overthinking".